# Will OS on old SSD corrupt new OS on new computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, installation, storage, software-conflict

I would like to remove the SSD from my old computer and install it in my new computer for use as extra file storage.  Potential issue:  the SSD contains the Windows 7 OS, and the new computer’s system is Windows 10 Pro.  I was not able to delete, remove or format the Windows 7 files when it was in the old computer.  Questions (1) will the mere installation of the SSD, with all its Windows 7 files, somehow inadvertently corrupt the OS in the new computer? (2) assuming the answer to the first question is “no,” what is the best way to remove all the files in the SSD after installation in the new computer and thus have a clean SSD available for extra storage?

The computer is a Dell 8930.

Comment: What exactly is PCL in the context of your question?

Comment: PCL is just a fact in case it may be useful for someone responding to my question.  I have no idea if it is useful.  It says, to me, the SSD is not on the motherboard.

Comment: PCI (Peripheral Component Interconnect)

Comment: I mistakenly confused the last letter in PCI as an "L"  It should be an "I"

Comment: You should edit your question to correct that mistake, even if you already have an answer, because if I was confused other people will be confused.

Comment: Thanks.  Done (entire sentence removed -- unnecessary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(1) will the mere installation of the SSD, with all its Windows 7 files, somehow inadvertently corrupt the OS in the new computer?*

If you keep the Windows 10 drive as the boot drive, no.

(2) what is the best way to remove all the files in the SSD after installation in the new computer and thus have a clean SSD available for extra storage?

You can see the Windows built-in [Disk Management](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-disk-management-2626080) app in action at https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001765.htm or you can use the command line (steps follow).

The [DISKPART](https://ss64.com/nt/diskpart-format.html) command which is standard in Windows 10.

A) From Windows 10, launch a Command Prompt  <kbd>WIN</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> CMD <kbd>Enter</kbd>

B) In that window, run `diskpart`

C) In diskpart, do `list disk` and you should see your boot drive as **Disk 0** and your newly added drive as **Disk 1**. If you don't, stop, go no further, and consult here!

```
DISKPART> list disks

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.16299.15

DISK        - Display a list of disks. For example, LIST DISK.
PARTITION   - Display a list of partitions on the selected disk.
              For example, LIST PARTITION.
VOLUME      - Display a list of volumes. For example, LIST VOLUME.
VDISK       - Displays a list of virtual disks.

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          XXX GB      0 B        *
  Disk 1    Online          YYY GB      0 B
```

D) Do `sel disk 1` to pick your newly added old Win 7 drive.

E) Do `del partition 1` to remove the first partition.

F) Do `list part` to check for any other partitions; if there are others, delete them, too, as in step E above.

G) Once all partitions on that drive are gone `create partition primary`

H) Do `FORMAT FS=NTFS LABEL="DATA" QUICK` to format it (you can change DATA to some other name if you wish).

I) Do `ASSIGN` to have Windows assign the next available drive letter.

J) Quit with `exit`.

K) Check in Explorer for your new empty drive.